# What are the opinions on the maximum size of a kezayit?

Tags: food, sukkah, mezonot-beracha

I am going to be travelling for business during Sukkot and won't have access to a sukkah. Therefore I'm looking for the opinion for the largest minimum size for eating a kezayit of mezonot outside a sukkah?

Comment: You should also ask your rabbi if you even need a sukkah while travelling.

Comment: Of course! The answer is no as long as I don't eat bread or mezonot larger than a kezayit.

Comment: You should also ask your rabbi if you can rely on the largest size of a kezayis. Almost certainly the absolutely largest size will be some obscure minority opinion which you should never rely on.

Comment: @richard No that's not necessarily the answer he will give you. The Talmud says travellers are exempt from a Sukkah entirely. This is why one should always ask a rabbi and not just assume one knows all the relevant laws

Comment: The Chazon Ish has a rather large size for a Kezayit - almost double of other opinions - but that is only as a stringency - and can't be used in this case where it's a leniency.

Comment: Why so many downvotes, people?

Comment: @ezra PErhaps becuase the OP is wasting everybody's time with a question based on a false premise, that was already pointed out to him. Or because [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85931/what-are-the-opinions-on-the-maximum-size-of-a-kezayit#comment272441_85931).

Comment: Off-topic as practical Halacha?

Comment: @DonielF No. The practical element just serves as the backdrop for the question. Which is incidentally one of the reasons why the current answer is not an answer.